# PySpark: difficulty implementing KMeans with mapreduce functions

Tags: python, pyspark, mapreduce, k-means, azure-databricks

I am currently tasekd in a Distributed DataBase class to create an implementation of kmeans with map reduce based approach (yes i know that there is a premade function for it but the task is specifically to do your own approach), and while i have figured out the approach itself, i am struggling with implementing it with the appropriate use of the map and reduce functions.

```
def Find_dist(x,y):
  sum = 0
  vec1= list(x)
  vec2 = list(y)
  for i in range(len(vec1)):
    sum = sum +(vec1[i]-vec2[i])*(vec1[i]-vec2[i])
  return sum

def mapper(cent, datapoint):
  min = Find_dist(datapoint,cent[0])
  closest = cent[0]
  for i in range(1,len(cent)):
    curr = Find_dist(datapoint,cent[i])
    if curr < min:
      min = curr
      closest = cent[i]
  yield closest,datapoint

def combine(x):
  Key = x[0]
  Values = x[1]
  sum = [0]*len(Key)
  counter = 0
  for datapoint in Values:
    vec = list(datapoint[0])
    counter = counter+1
    sum = sum+vec
  point = Row(vec)
  result = (counter,point)
  yield Key, result

def Reducer(x):
  Key = x[0]
  Values = x[1]
  sum = [0]*len(Key)
  counter = 0
  for datapoint in Values:
    vec = list(datapoint[0])
    counter = counter+1
    sum = sum+vec
  avg = [0]*len(Key)
  for i in range(len(Key)):
    avg[i] = sum[i]/counter
  centroid = Row(avg)
  yield Key, centroid

def kmeans_fit(data,k,max_iter):
  centers = data.rdd.takeSample(False,k,seed=42)
  for i in range(max_iter):
    mapped = data.rdd.map(lambda x: mapper(centers,x))
    combined = mapped.reduceByKeyLocally(lambda x: combiner(x))
    reduced = combined.reduceByKey(lambda x: Reducer(x)).collect()
    flag = True
    for i in range(k):
      if(reduced[i][1] != reduced[i][0] ):
        for j in range(k):
          centers[i] = reduced[i][1]
        flag = False
        break
    if (flag):
      break
  return centers
data = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/ddscoursedatabricksstg/ddscoursedatabricksdata/random_data.parquet")
kmeans_fit(data,5,10)
```

My main issue for the most part is I encounter difficulty in the usage of dataframes and the map, reducebykeylocally and reducebykey fucntions. 
Currently the run fails at calling reduceByKeyLocally(lambda x: combiner(x)) because "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)", and i really need to get this all working properly soon, so please, anyone i would love assistance on this, and thank you in advance, I will be very grateful for any help!